# Artifacts on some fonts in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts

I'm getting a really weird distortion of some fonts in Chrome and I don't know why. The font looks messy and corrupted. Any ideas? The occurs on many sites, but this screenshot is from Youtube.

[image]

Comment: Additional info: This does not occur on Firefox and IE, and I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Solved... I had EZGDI installed to improve font rendering in windows. I uninstalled it and all my fonts look normal now. (aside from being ugly aliased windows rendering again... better than messed up)

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude chrome.exe in the ezgdi.ini file. This is my setup. I just added all of the software that don't play well with EzGDI.

```
[ExcludeModule]
DWM.EXE
WerFault.exe
chrome.exe
terminal.exe
fontview.exe
itunes.exe
skype.exe
```